# Regularly update database without browser/user

Tags: php, mysql, live, arduino

I currently have a MySQL database which I was hoping to use to store regularly updated data from a temperature sensor connected to the internet.

I currently have a page that, when opened, will grab the current temperature and the current timestamp and add it as an entry to the database, but I was looking for a way to do that without me refreshing the page every 5 seconds.

Detail:
The data comes from an Arduino Ethernet, posted to an IP address.
Currently, I'm using cURL to grab the data from the IP, add a timestamp and save it to the DB.
Obviously only updates when the page is refreshed (it uses PHP).

Here is a live feed of the data - http://wetdreams.org.uk/ChrisProject/UI/live_graph_two.html

TL;DR - Basically I need a middle man to grab the data from the IP and post it to a MySQL

**Edit:** Thanks for all the advice. There might be a little bit of confusion, I'm looking for a solution that (ideally) doesn't require a computer to be on at all (other than the Server containing Database). Since I'm looking to store data over long periods of time (weeks), I'd like to set it up and leave a script running on the server (or Arduino) that gets the temp and posts it to the Database.

In my head I would like to have a page on the server that automatically (without any browser open, or any other prompting other than a timer) calls a PHP script.

Hope that clears things up!

Comment: It looks like the arduino updates the database, so crontab would be the wrong solution. It'd be more of an ajax solution.

Comment: Still, if the implements a [simple http server](http://arduino.cc/en/Tutorial/WebServer) on the Arduino, display the current temperature on the page it is serving, it would be trivial to grab that data using a bash script and insert it into a db.

Comment: @Sibster I think a http server on the Arduino would be overkill, the Arduino can just post the data straight into a database.

Comment: I don't know anything about Cron (other than a quick glance at Wikipedia..) - is it like a page I can just upload to my server and it automatically schedules jobs?
ps. see question edit, might clear things up

Answer (score 0, accepted):

In this case, the best solution was using the Arduino to post a request to a PHP script which done its thing and added the retrieved value to a database. The way I have it running just now (for simplicity sake) is with a GET request from the Arduino using the EthernetClient.

Code:

```
char server[] = "www.example.com";
```

and

```
if(client.connect(server, 80)){
  client.println("GET /test.php?input_val=99 HTTP/1.0");
  client.println("HOST: www.example.com");
}
```

However, since I'd already built my website around the fact that the data was posted to an independent server/IP*, I opted to use cron to schedule a task. In this case I wanted to update my DB every 5 - 10 seconds. However, I'm piggybacking on somebody else's server, so I contacted the server owner and asked them to set up a cron job calling "/mysubdir/cron_update.php" every minute (the fastest cron can call). From there I done a bit of 'ScriptCeption' and within the PHP script, completed my calls every 10 seconds for a minute before finishing the script.

Thanks to everybody who helped me out, I'm posting this here as a complete answer and explanation, because technically everybody was correct.

Answer (score 2):

you can post directly to web server from your arduino using [ArduinoEtherenetClient](http://arduino.cc/en/Reference/EthernetClient) (click link to get example)

`POST /insertData.php` - in insertData.php use `$_POST["tempCaptured"]` to get the temp value and insert that in db.

Good article on using ArduinoEthernetClient http://interactive-matter.eu/how-to/arduino-http-client-library/

Comment: Inserting stuff into a database? Use POST, not GET.

Comment: Using GET for that would violate the HTTP specification, and discard all the protections against accidental data insertion that POST offers.

Comment: It's writing stuff to a database. It needs POST.

Comment: Oh sorry forget to change that

Answer (score 1):

Write a code(ping.php) which pings this url at fixed intervals.

Now, setup a [cronjob](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Cron) which runs this code at fixed intervals.

Your cron can be `0 */2 * * *  PATH_TO_{ping.php} // will run every 2 hours`

your ping.php file will connect to the live feed, grab the data and store results to the db.:

Comment: Cronjob has been mentioned, it seems more economical to me to let the Arduino send the data out, instead of a computer pulling the data out.

Comment: @BradleyForster - Do you know of an easy way to post to a MySQL from Arduino? The problems are that you can't run any server-side scripts from an Arduino because its obviously not got PHP installed.

Comment: @ChrisM [EthernetClient](http://arduino.cc/en/Reference/EthernetClient) previously posted would be the simplest. Then you just create a php file on your server with the database code, and post a url like /process.php?temp=34.1&timestamp=0000000 and whatever other data you want to store.

Comment: Otherwise if your familiar with C/C++ (opposed to Arduino construct) you can use a C database library. I would imagine would be more lightweight, but with less support.

Answer (score 0):

You can use JavaScript to auto refresh the page

```
<script type="text/javascript">
    function timedRefresh(timeoutPeriod) {
        setTimeout("location.reload(true);", timeoutPeriod);
}
</script>
```

A better solution would be ajax and send the date regulary in the background to the database.

Another way is to use a [PHP-CLI script](http://php.net/manual/en/features.commandline.php) and to schedule it with [cron jobs](http://www.unixgeeks.org/security/newbie/unix/cron-1.html) that gets the values from your sensor automatically.

Comment: I got the impression he doesn't want refreshing.

Answer (score 0):

If I understand the problem. You just need a replacement for refreshing the web page every 5 seconds?
Not getting the data?

I would setup an ajax connection, and have the php run in a kind of infinite loop. echoing new data back to your javascript to update the graph. The PHP loop would have to have a timeout check to eventually close the script.

Comment: I was thinking about Ajax, but that would require me to have a browser open all the time, not ideal for this solution (although could be a last resort).
Check the question edit, that might clear things up?

Comment: @ChrisM yeah that would be the front end. Nothing to do with the arduino itself. For that you would either save the log as a txt file on your device, and read the data when a browser opens. Or have the Arduino post the data straight to a database. The example by Sandeep Manne would be my recommendation.